# Any known WMS/WFS providers?

Tags: wms, wfs

I searched on Google, found few things, aren't there many of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "cheat" and use the fact WMS is web-based to find them yourselves with some cunning searches.
A search for the following should yield WMS servers:

`"request=getcapabilities" "SERVICE=WMS" filetype:xml`

Unfortunately many modern search engines (including Google) assume you mean something else despite the quotes, so not all results are what they should be.

Change the `WMS` to `WFS` or whichever service you want as appropriate. The "filetype:XML" isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: Excellent idea. Just a slight revision, to search xml files in google the "fileype" switch is used instead of "format". http://www.google.com/search?q="request=getcapabilities""SERVICE=WMS"filetype:xml

Comment: Ooops, that's the one I was going for. Corrected. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I once found this on the internet: http://www.skylab-mobilesystems.com/en/wms_serverlist.html

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Something to note - it is over three years old: "generated on 2009-03-12"

Answer (score 1):

If you search for [claudius.ptolomaeus@gmail.com](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=claudius.ptolomaeus@gmail.com) you'll find lots of WMS (and WFS, WCS etc) that he is the default GeoServer administrator for.